# Parsing Addresses with GeoPanda's GeoDataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, geospatial

Long time reader of **Code Review** with my first question. I'm self-taught and suspect this code can be improved. The project is really important to me and the team and I could really use the help.

I'm using this as part of a larger script run through the terminal which takes a `GeoDataFrame` and adds the GPS coordinates as a `Point` per the specification, and then outputs a GDF again. (I then export it as a `geojson` file.) So far it's running through ~3500 rows in about 2 hours - which is fine - but I don't think I'm using many coding best practices. I'd like to make it as robust as possible because we have some datasets to run through that are +15000 rows. Does anyone have any feedback on this script?

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point
import geopy as gpy
from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3
from geopy.extra.rate_limiter import RateLimiter
from geopy.exc import GeocoderTimedOut
from geopy.location import Location

def addressParsing(gdf_obj, delayseconds):
    """
    This takes a whole GeoDataFrame and adds the Geo Coords from the standard address
    before returning the udpated Geodataframe
    """
    # Returned class obj if None
    site = Location("0", (0.0, 0.0, 0.0))

    def do_geocode(address):
        try:
            return geocode_with_delay(address)
        except GeocoderTimedOut:
            return geocode_with_delay(address)

    print(f"starting parser: {gdf_obj.shape}, estimated time: {round(delayseconds * gdf_obj.shape[0] / 60, 2)} min")

    # Initiate geocoder
    geolocator = GoogleV3(api_key=g_api_key)

    # Create a geopy rate limiter class:
    geocode_with_delay = RateLimiter(
        geolocator.geocode,
        error_wait_seconds=delayseconds + 20,
        min_delay_seconds=delayseconds,
        swallow_exceptions=True,
        return_value_on_exception= site
        )

    # Apply the geocoder with delay using the rate limiter:
    gdf_obj['temp'] = gdf_obj['Address'].apply(do_geocode)

    # Get point coordinates from the GeoPy location object on each row, drop z vector data:
    gdf_obj["coords"] = gdf_obj['temp'].apply(lambda loc: tuple(loc.point)[:2] if loc else tuple(site.point)[:2])

    # Create shapely point objects to geometry column:
    gdf_obj["geometry"] = gdf_obj["coords"].apply(Point)

    # Drop intermediate columns
    gdf_obj = gdf_obj.drop(["temp", "coords"], axis=1)

    print("FINISHED - conversion successful - check shape")
    return gdf_obj
```

Comment: _Long time reader of Code Review with my first question_ - Welcome, that's exciting :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Nomenclature

Function names should be snake_case per PEP8, i.e. `address_parsing`.

### Type hinting

For function parameters and return values mainly, type hinting will help define your signatures. For example, `delayseconds` would probably become `delay_seconds: float`, and `gdf_obj: dict` if you don't know a lot about the structure of the dictionary. So:

```
def address_parsing(gdf_obj: dict, delay_seconds: float) -> dict:
```

### Retries:

```
    try:
        return geocode_with_delay(address)
    except GeocoderTimedOut:
        return geocode_with_delay(address)
```

Effectively this will ignore up to one `GeocoderTimedOut` and retry, but if it occurs twice the exception will fall through. A saner way to represent this is:

```
TRIES = 2
# ...

for retry in range(TRIES):
  try:
    return geocode_with_delay(address)
  except GeocoderTimedOut as e:
    print('Geocoder timed out')
raise e
```

### Temporary variables

The expression

```
round(delayseconds * gdf_obj.shape[0] / 60, 2)
```

is complex enough that it should be assigned to a variable. That said, you're better off using Python's actual time-handling features:

```
from datetime import timedelta
# ...

est_time = timedelta(seconds=delayseconds * gdf_obj.shape[0])
print(f'Estimated time: {est_time}')  # will do pretty formatting
```

Comment: `gdf_object` is probably some subclass of a pandas dataframe

Comment: Man I love SE. That is just so helpful as a self-directed learner.

Answer (score 3):

Nesting function definitions can often be useful, but it's not what you should normally do. Really, everything should be moved *outside* of the function unless there's a reason (including readability) for it to be inside.

I would also suggest that `delayseconds` could be an external setting. Or give it a default value. Also, it seems likely that `delayseconds` is a big part of why the script takes so long!

I'll assume you want `delayseconds` as a parameter, so I'll use functools to help keep it abstract.

`do_geocode` could be more descriptively named.

`site` needs a better name. Also it looks like you're building a whole object and only using part of it, but I may have misunderstood.

Rather than having temporary columns, package your computation up into a single applyable step.

```py
from functools import partial

import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point
import geopy as gpy
from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3
from geopy.extra.rate_limiter import RateLimiter
from geopy.exc import GeocoderTimedOut
from geopy.location import Location


default_coordinates = (0.0, 0.0)

# Initiate geocoder
geolocator = GoogleV3(api_key=g_api_key)

# Create a geopy rate limiter class:
def geocode_with_delay(delayseconds):
    return RateLimiter(
        geolocator.geocode,
        error_wait_seconds=delayseconds + 20,
        min_delay_seconds=delayseconds,
        swallow_exceptions=True,
        return_value_on_exception= site
    )

def point_of_location(loc):
    if loc:
        return Point(tuple(loc.point)[:2])
    else:
        return Point(default_coordinates)

def try_geocode(address, geo_coder):
    try:
        return point_of_location(geo_coder(address))
    except GeocoderTimedOut:
        return point_of_location(geo_coder(address)) # Is there a reason not to just have a default Point()?

def addressParsing(gdf_obj, delayseconds = 0):
    """
    This takes a whole GeoDataFrame and adds the Geo Coords from the standard address
    before returning the udpated Geodataframe
    """

    print(f"starting parser: {gdf_obj.shape}, estimated time: {round(delayseconds * gdf_obj.shape[0] / 60, 2)} min")

    rate_limited = geocode_with_delay(delayseconds)
    geocode_action = partial(try_geocode, geo_coder=rate_limited)

    # Apply the geocoder with delay using the rate limiter:
    gdf_obj['geometry'] = gdf_obj['Address'].apply(geocode_action)

    print("FINISHED - conversion successful - check shape")
    return gdf_obj
```

I haven't tested this even to see if it runs.

Comment: I haven't attempted to incorporate @Reinderien's advice, which is all good advice and I think compatible with the changes I suggested.